# Developing universal in Xcode 6+

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have Xcode 6 installed and I'm trying to develop an universal app. Before Xcode 6, you had to create 2 separate Storyboards for iPad and iPhone and you could set it in the Deployment Info.
How to manage storyboard without using **Autolayout** and **size clas**s ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use auto-layout and size classes, uncheck the corresponding checkboxes while in storyboard's "File Inspector" utility view (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>):

[image]